# I have a strange bug

Tags: go

given are the following 2 functions.

```
func main() {
    index := int(0)

    for {
        Loop(index)
        index = (index + 1) % 86400 // Max interval: 1 day
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func Loop(index int) {
    if index%10 == 0 {
        go doSomething...
    }
}
```

I want to execute something every 10/60/3600 seconds. So I thought an incrementing index with modulo should do this.

But what I noticed (especially on high traffic servers) that it appears to skip some of that loops.

I looked in my logs and sometimes there is something every 10 seconds but sometimes there is a gap up to 1 minute.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: There is definitely not a "go bug with modulo" - the modulus operator in Go works just fine. This is an app issue. Is your CPU usage at or near max?

Comment: no. near 0%. it also not a network issue and there is no single error in my runtime (and i log nearly everything)

Comment: It's near 0% yet "especially on high traffic servers"?

Comment: Where is the log message you're looking for? Inside `doSomething`?

Comment: sry. ignore that "high traffic" statement. there is only ~500kb/s traffic. but it is different to those instances where nearly 0 traffic arrives. i know i described it horrible, but this is real. i think i solved it by using "time.Since().Seconds() > 10". now it seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using a [`time.Ticker`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker) to perform some action every N seconds. That way, you use built-in timers and only wake the CPU when something needs to be done. Even if the CPU is not heavily used, `time.Sleep` and a for loop is not the most reliable way to schedule tasks. For example (from the link above):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        done <- true
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Done!")
            return
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Println("Current time: ", t)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much :) "and a for loop is not the most reliable way to schedule tasks" => i think i found an exception where it not worked ;)

Comment: You're welcome! It's a bit counter-intuitive, but good to be aware of. Also, if an answer helps, you may want to mark it as accepted. No pressure. :)

Comment: sry, only got 14 reps. 15 reps guys can vote for "accepted" :(

Comment: do you also have an idea why my first approach didnt work? i guess that some "bug" just skipped the index so that index%10 was just randomly 0 and not every 10 seconds. and there is no similar bug description elsewhere in the internet. this is not possible that i was the first person who noticed that?

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the modulo operation. I suspect it's because one (or many) of the calls to `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)` took longer than 1 second. This is not unlikely if it's been running for many hours/days.